# How to use nl2br() to handle string with '\r\n'?

Tags: php, mysql, nl2br

I am retrieving a product description value stored in database from admin through textarea upon form submit. When I select the description from database I get `$description = $row['description'];` and I would like to echo $description on main page like this: `echo nl2br($description);` but I see `"\r\n"` characters instead of making new rows. From what I've found here and on the net, your string must be used between double quotes, like this:

```
echo nl2br("Hello, \r\n This is the description");
```

Now, the value of `$description` from database is in fact `"Hello, \r\n This is the description"` but in my script I have to use it like this:

```
echo nl2br($description);
```

Which does not make br's, it is outputing `\r\n` instead. So, what can I do, I can't use double quotes here, from my experience.

Comment: Is it stored with the backslashes escaped as in `\\r\\n`?  `nl2br()` should work with no problems on a variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *could* translate them into their respective escape sequences before passing the string through `nl2br()`, like this:

```
$description = nl2br(str_replace('\\r\\n', "\r\n", $description));
```

But what are the literal escapes doing in your database in the first place?

Comment: How should I handle $_POST['description'] upon database inserting in order to keep new lines intact ? Thanks.

Comment: @Manny Calavera: If you're not already using a textarea, you should use that. If you want to ensure `\r\n` always becomes a real newline, I guess you can simply run `str_replace()` before inserting, so you don't have to do it after fetching.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the literal value of `\r\n` in your database, not the actual characters they represent.

Verify this in your database. If you see `\r\n` in the description field, then you're probably escaping the backslash when you're storing the data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your text contains the individual characters `\`, `r`, `\`, and `n`, and does not contain actual newline characters. As such, `str_replace()` should get the job done:

```
echo str_replace('\r\n', '<br>', $description);
```

Answer (score -2):

The nl2br can take a second (optional) argument for "is_xhtml" which will convert the `\r\n` into a `<br>` for you. Just change your line to:

```
echo nl2br($description, TRUE);
```

Comment: the optional argument is true by default.